# How to retrieve Medium reading list for a user from the API using python?

Tags: python, medium.com-publishing-api

From Medium API docs I can see how to retrieve publications and create posts, but it doesn't mention retrieving reading list. Is retrieving reading list for a user currently possible using the Medium's API?

Answer (score 1):

The [Medium API documentation](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs) clearly states the endpoints available.
Their `Listing the user's publications` [endpoint](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs#listing-the-users-publications) states:

> Returns a full list of publications that the user is related to in some way: This includes all publications the user is **subscribed to**, writes to, or edits. This endpoint offers a set of data similar to what you’ll see at https://medium.com/me/publications when logged in.

So if by "reading list" you mean the list of publications the user is subscribed to than yes, you can retrieve it via:

`GET https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{{userId}}/publications`

Comment: here "reading list" means the articles which I saved for further reading. Below is the url where we can get list of articles we saved for future reference

https://medium.com/me/list/queue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is currently possible to retrieve reading list. According to the documentation api's it is not part of that list.

Comment: If you debug the Android app you see that it does api.medium.com:443 when you refresh the readling list, but I can't seem to decrypt the HTTPS to see what params it's sending. GraphQL variant on the web page doesn't have 'reading time' sort option, so of no interest to me : ( Options: REVERSE_CHRON, RECOMMENDS, TOP, TOP_CATALOG